# Check if json contains key

Tags: javascript, json

I want to search through a JSON file to see if it has contains the email address I'm searching for (example@mail.com in the code below). However, it doesn't work.

```
function contains(arr, key, val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i][key] === val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

emailRecord = JSON.parse(req.responseText); //Got this from an XMLHttpRequest.

if(contains(fullEmailRecord, "email", "example@mail.com")) 
{
   console.log("LOGGED IN")
}
```

The JSON:

```
[
  {
    "email": "example@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "mail@example.com"
  }
]
```

```js
function contains(arr, key, val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i][key] === val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

const fullEmailRecord = [
  {
    "email": "example@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "mail@example.com"
  }
];

if(contains(fullEmailRecord, "email", "example@mail.com")) 
{
   console.log("LOGGED IN")
}
```

Comment: Looks to work here

Comment: Oh, but you're using `emailRecord = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` but then passing in `if(contains(fullEmailRecord,`, a different variable - looks like typo

Answer (score 0):

It works in the code snippet, but not in the original piece of code due to the variable `fullEmailRecord` being used instead of `emailRecord` .

Comment: The error I'm receiving is 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at contains (background.js:8)
    at background.js:37`

Comment: Yes, your variable `fullEmailRecord` is not defined, and `emailRecord ` is the one with your array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it much simple than that, search it in the string instead of json like this:

```
req.responseText.contains("example@mail.com")
```

or

```
req.responseText.indexOf("example@mail.com") > -1
```

Complete use:

```
if (req.responseText.contains("example@mail.com")) {
   console.log("LOGGED IN")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
arr.map(e => e.email === 'YOUR EMAIL');
```

if that returns an object then it exists

in other words you can change your function to this

```
function contains(arr, key, val) {
  return arr.map(e => e[key] === val)
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that: 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: that means your array you are putting in is not an array...  is your data an array?

Comment: This is the response I get: `[{"email":"example@mail.com"},{"email":"mail@example.com"}]`

Comment: Try this fiddle.... https://jsfiddle.net/eddsters/da9nLkh5/

Open your console and see what is showing.  When it is an array it works for me.